# Enable TLS in bitnami Redis Pod - Certificate issue

Tags: ssl, redis, certificate, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I am trying to enable TLS in my redis cluster.
Followed this article to create self signed certificate.

https://blog.devolutions.net/2020/07/tutorial-how-to-generate-secure-self-signed-server-and-client-certificates-with-openssl/

After generation of certificates followed the steps as given by bitnami documentation as below:-
https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/infrastructure/redis/administration/enable-tls/

deployed using below

```
tls.enabled="true"
tls.certificatesSecret="certificates-tls-secret"
tls.certFilename="server.crt"
tls.certKeyFilename="server.key"
tls.certCAFilename="ca.crt"
```

But after this not able to start redis pod, getting below error

Error accepting a client connection: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca

I am guessing some issue with certificate chain but cannot figure out what. Can someone point me in right direction?

Comment: does Redis server CA trust client's certificate?, log message implies otherwise.

Comment: I have created server certificate using ca, 
```openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 1000 -sha256```